# set youtube video default quality to HD

Tags: youtube, camtasia

I have a youtube video that I want to be by default HD (720), not the auto set by youtube (360).
All I found was I can configure what I'll see from other user's video, but I can't find where I set the quality the users how watch *my* video would have by default.
I'm using Camtasia 8 for the video.  Maybe I need to configure it there?

Any hint would be great.

Perhaps nobody knows with this new youtube layout.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that impossible to configure- You can only configure embed videos.
I solved this by simply prompting the user with those youtube comment to toggle HD, and hope they would.

Answer (score 0):

I think youtube says it best here describing the way you can and should embed youtube videos.

http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178264

Comment: Hey, I'm not talking about emdeding, but about the video itself. Seems there's no way to do that.